# How to make Ansible run batch of tasks on Cluster Node's - node by node

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an ansible playbook which looks roughly like the following.
I need **Zero Downtime Upgrade start** and **Zero Downtime Upgrade completed steps.** will run once to put\remove cluser into upgrade mode.
in addition I need all the tasks into **Block** will be run only on one node on same time and continue to next node once we get HTTP 200

Could you please review the yml file ? currently I get **ERROR! 'uri' is not a valid attribute for a Block** and if you have any suggestion to improve it.

```yaml
---
- name: Zero Downtime Upgrade start
  hosts: atl
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    vars.yml
  tasks:
   - name: get Cluster state
     run_once: true
     uri:
      url: https://{{ base_url }}.XXX.com/rest/api/2/cluster/zdu/state
      headers:
       Content-Type: application/json
      force_basic_auth: true
      validate_certs: false
      user: XXX
      password: XXX
     register: response
  #  - name: debug.
  #    debug: var=response
  #    run_once: true
   - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade API
     run_once: true
     uri:
      url: https://{{ base_url }}.XXX.com/rest/api/2/cluster/zdu/start
      method: POST
      validate_certs: false
      headers:
       Content-Type: application/json
      force_basic_auth: true
      user: XXX
      password: XXX
      status_code: 201
#     register: response
     when: response.json.state == 'STABLE'
  #  - name: debug.
  #    run_once: true
  #    debug: var=response
   - block:
      - name: create dir for backup configuration
        file:
          path: "{{ atl_backup_conf }}"
          state: directory
          mode: '0755'
          owner: atl
          group: atl
      - name: backup configuration files
        copy:
          src: "{{ item }}"
          dest: "{{ atl_backup_conf }}"
    #      backup: true
          remote_src: true
          owner: atl
          group: atl
        with_items:
          - "{{ atl_app }}/bin/setenv.sh"
        ignore_errors: true
      - name: "stop atl service on {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node"
        #shell: /etc/init.d/atl stop
        systemd:
          name: atl
          state: stopped
        become: yes
- name: Zero Downtime Upgrade completed steps.
     hosts: atl
     vars_files:
      vars.yml
     tasks: 
     - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade API change to Stable status.
       run_once: true
       uri:
        url: https://{{ base_url }}.XXX.com/rest/api/2/cluster/zdu/approve
        method: POST
        validate_certs: false
        headers:
          Content-Type: application/json
        force_basic_auth: true
        user: XXX
        password: XXX
        status_code: 409 , 200
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed a dash in front of `block`.

Removing all attributes your tasks look like this:

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: get Cluster state
  - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade API
    block:
# ^-- dash missing
      - name: "Upgrade {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node."
      - name: create dir for backup configuration
      - name: "stop atl service on {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node"
      - name: Install New atl Version.
    - name: Configure systemd service.
#   ^-- indented incorrectly
      - name: Reload Enable and Start atl.service
      - name: health checks - trigger GET node state.
```

As you see, `block` is currently an attribute for the previous task, it should be at the level of `tasks` instead.

Additionally, your task `Configure systemd service.` is not indented correctly, it should be at the same level as the other tasks.

```yaml
  tasks:
  - name: get Cluster state
  - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade API
  - block:
# ^-- added missing dash
      - name: "Upgrade {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node."
      - name: create dir for backup configuration
      - name: "stop atl service on {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node"
      - name: Install New atl Version.
      - name: Configure systemd service.
#     ^-- indented correctly
      - name: Reload Enable and Start atl.service
      - name: health checks - trigger GET node state.
```

YAML is extremely picky about indentation.

Comment: `- name: Zero Downtime Upgrade start
  hosts: atl
  serial: 1
  gather_facts: false
  vars_files:
    vars.yml
  tasks:
  - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade API
  - block:
      - name: "Upgrade {{ ansible_hostname }} atl node."
      - name: create dir for backup configuration
      - name: "stop atl service atl node"
      - name: health checks - trigger GET node state.
        retries: 720
        delay: 5 
- name: Zero Downtime Upgrade completed steps.
  hosts: atl
  tasks:
  - name: trigger Zero Downtime upgrade
    run_once: true
    uri:`

Comment: thank you for your reply ,not sure how can I make it more readable in comment area.?! I need 2 first commands under tasks: will be run one time but all commands under - block: will be exec on all nodes but **node by node** and in the end again from **Upgrade completed steps.** will be run one time on one of the node.

Comment: You can't make it readable in the comments. If you have something to add to your existing question, edit it. If you encounter a new problem, it's better to accept the answer that helped you and ask a new question with the new problem.

Comment: once I run the playbook I get the error : `ERROR! no module/action detected in task.

The error appears to be in main_new.yml': line 41, column 9, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

   - block:
      - name: Upgrade atl node.
        ^ here
`
I use ansible-playbook 2.10.9 , do you sure for `- block:` module syntax ? I see there is exist `block:` with out -

Comment: Yes, [I'm sure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html).

Comment: We can't tell you what's wrong exactly without seeing the current state of your playbook.

Comment: unfortunately,I can't shared here because the comments not readable.any idea how can I share the current state ?

Comment: As I already told you: edit your question. Don't remove what's already in there, just add it below.

Comment: it gave me error while try to add so I update it based on your last comment

Comment: I just want to we on same page - I need all tasks under 'get Cluster state' and 'get Cluster state' will be exec one time (run_once=true) and all the tasks inside the -block: will be exec node by node, I mean first to run all tasks on first node in atl hosts group once node is up mean I get HTTP=200 it can proceed to next node in atl hosts group and so on. once complete the '-block:' tasks can proceed and run tasks under 'Zero Downtime Upgrade completed steps.' only on one of the node (run_once=true) I hope it more clear now

Comment: thank you, I managed it.